# may i use multiple t-tests to examine group differences?

Tags: t-test, group-differences, manova

I've got a critical comment on my recent manuscript on cultural comparisons. There were two different samples depending on collection method (classroom vs. online) in both culture A and culture B. So I conducted a MANOVA in SPSS with the "collection method" and "culture" as independent variables, age as a covariate, and a set of 8 target variables as dependent variables. 
As collection method difference was not my interest, I only reported the results of culture main effect, which was none. But I also found  crossover effects between country and collection method on a few variables.
However, the reviewer questioned this method wondering if such t-tests would be the most appropriate one and asked me to have it checked by an expert in this kind of statistics. Can anyone help me?